# How to find out if variable item contains specific words in Python?

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, if-statement

I have created the following variable, which captures the function from a Point object I created:

```
j = i.getfunction()
print(j)
```

The `print(j)` outputs something like this whenever it's called:

```
<function draw_H at 0x1057ce268>
```

What I want to do is find out if the item attached to the variable contains certain words. For instance, using the `print(j)` output above, I want to find out if `j` contains `draw_H`, like so:

```
if j contains draw_H:
    # Run this code
```

**How would I do this? Specifically, how would I find out if an item attached to a variable contains a certain word?** Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `draw_H` is not value. Function  `<function draw_H at 0x1057ce268>` is value attached to variable.  `draw_H` is name of function attached to variable.

Comment: @furas So, how would I capture the name of the function?

Comment: someone already shows solution - `j.__name__ == "draw_H"`

Comment: @furas Yeah, he deleted his comment, and I did not clearly see what he wrote. I'll try that.

Comment: or `if "draw_H" in j.__name__:`.  `j.__name__` is a string so you can use other string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `__name__` attribute:

```
print (j.__name__)
```

to test for a substring do:

```
if "draw_H" in j.__name__:
    <do stuff>
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks!